# Impedance for an equivalent circuit

Tags: voltage, time, function

In: *Richard Reidl, N.O. Sokal & Laszlo Balogh (1990). **A Novel Soft-Switching Full-Bridge DC/DC Converter: Analysis, Design Considerations, and Experimental Results at 1.5 kW, 100 kHz**. IEEE Transactions on Power Electronics. 6. 162 - 172*, the following schematic diagram converter  has the transition from the passive state to the active state, with the following mentions:

[image]

- during the passive state S2 and S4 were active
- during the passive state the Transformer's secondary is shorted
- C2 represents the parasitic capacitance ( S4, Snubber if exists, Transformer, etc )
- since the transition starts from the passive state Vc2(0) = 0V , the potential difference on the capacitance C2 is zero
- current I1 is the current that slowly decays during the passive state

The equivalent circuit for that transition Passive - Active is:

[image]

The voltage on C2 is calculated using the following formula:

$$\begin{aligned}
V_{C2}(t) =& I_1\sqrt{\frac{L_1+L_C}{C_2}}\sin{\omega t}
\end{aligned}$$

If you can help me understand how the author calculated the impedance, mathematically step-by-step, specifically this:

$$\begin{aligned}
\sqrt{\frac{L_1+L_C}{C_2}}\sin{\omega t}
\end{aligned}$$

I know how basically to manipulate complex numbers, but I simply cannot have the same result. I need to treat it like a voltage divider, right? Something like this:

$$\begin{aligned}
Z(t) ={\frac{{\frac{1}{j\omega tC_2}}}{{\frac{1}{j\omega t C_2}}+j\omega t(L_1+L_C)}}
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: The system is a full bridge converter. The phases are alternating, in the first phase S1-S4 enter into conduction so that the voltage on the primary Vp=Vi. In the second and fourth phase the four transistors are all off. In the third phase, vice versa, S2 and S3 conduct so that V.p=-Vi. The voltage on the primary is a square wave of amplitude Vi/n with n=n1/n2, so it can be written that the rectified and filtered voltage has a value equal to: Vo=2∙Vi∙ton/(n∙T ) (when L1 and L2 are shorted and C1 and C2 absent. ).

Comment: I have a tangential question - just to satisfy my curiosity, since the problem I'll mention is rather widespread. It seems that you've copy-pasted or exported images from CircuitLab into the question. This seems odd, given that the question and answer editor on this site has built-in CircuitLab button, making the schematics easy to edit by others, copy and simulate, etc. Somehow, many question askers do it the hard way. It'd be interesting (to me at least) to know why, because clearly there is some user experience factor that makes people do it the hard way and not the simple way...

Comment: @Franc incorrect, in the 2nd and fourth phase the transistors are **not** all off (as defined clearly in the question).

Comment: You will find extensive literature on the subject by consulting the IEEE Transaction on POWER ELECTRONICS.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica Well, in order to edit the schematic, that schematic needs to work when you pres run. For it to work I need to calculate the On and Off time, the phase shifting of the switches...and that is what I am trying to understand by reading the paper and frankly I didn't even know that stack electrical has an in build "api" circuitlab. I was baffled to learn that you can add mathematical equations <3

Comment: @Franc As I understood, in the passive state ( 2 and 4 phase ) some transistors are open. For example: the positive passive ( 2nd phase ) starts with turn-off of S1 while S4 remains open to facilitate a path for the current from the leakage and commutation inductor. In the same time, the same current starts to discharge the stray capacitance of the S2 ( noted with C2 ) to facilitate the soft-switching of the of S2 which will be turn-on during the passive state. My curiosity is how mathematically step by step the author came up with that formula.

Comment: *stray capacitance of the S2 ( noted with C1 )

Comment: @Franc - In [this earlier comment](/posts/comments/1864291) which you posted, it started by saying "You..." but it's not clear who you meant. In case you're not aware, comments can be addressed to a specific user (within limits e.g. that user must have posted a previous, still visible, comment on the same post). This feature is documented in [this article on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019) which is linked from the [main SE FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931). To help the right person know you are addressing them, please consider using the `@username` feature.

Comment: Do you agree that the voltages (PWM) that drive the transistors S1-S4 are in fact trains of pulses with period T, of constant amplitude duration ton, and with duty-cycle ton/T with ton less than T /2? While the pulse train that drives S2-S3 is identical to the previous one but delayed by T/2. It therefore turns out that in a certain time interval all four transistors do not conduct. To simplify and carry out an analysis in the Laplace domain, we can consider, as is commonly done, the transistors as switches and determine and study the circuit in the various phases. It is a difficult task.

Comment: @SamGison I apologize, I address the author of the post I33SoDA.

Comment: @Franc Yes. Correct. I cannot explain why the entire time when I was reading the paper I was thinking about Phase Shift. I am so sorry for the trouble!! Because in Pulse Width Modulation the Duty can be less than T/2 ( in order to have a positive and negative front identical in order to not saturate the Trafo ) indeed, there is a small period of time in which all of them are off. I am truly sorry!

Comment: @Franc - Thanks for explaining, I actually thought you meant someone else! FYI the author of a post is notified of every comment added to that post. However until they have added a comment of their own, then the author's name will not "auto-complete" if you type `@` and start typing their name. So here is what I do: If I am addressing the author of a post, but they did not yet add a comment (so `@their-name` won't work normally) I just add their name without `@`. As I said, the author of a post gets notified of every comment. The point is just to make it clear who the intended addressee is.

Comment: @SamGibson I was convinced that if my reply is addressed to one of the people who replied to the post, then I use @-name of the person, otherwise not. It is not so?

Comment: i33SoDA Don't worry!

Comment: @Franc - The problem is that if multiple people have been involved in comments on a post, and someone writes a comment which does not mention a name, then the intended recipient of that comment is ambiguous :( || Some people (wrongly) believe that if they type a comment without specifying a name, then the intended recipient should be assumed to be the comment immediately before the one they typed. Some other people (wrongly) believe that if they type a comment without specifying a name, then it should be taken as a general comment to everyone and everyone should be considered as the recipient!